# How to compile and run freeradius using Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse-cdt, freeradius

Hi I am new to Freeradius and C, I am trying to create modules for Freeradius. I am able to compile it using CDT environment but not able to run server.
Since build will only build make command, when I try to run radiusd with argument X , it gives the 
no file error for raduis.conf since make install not executed
Did anyone tried to debug environment where we can debug using Any ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant debug the free-radius server code using the Eclipse CDT since there are lot of dependence.

You can use the Eclipse to compile and code.